# what do I do about malformed line 57

Tags: software-center, skype, software-sources

my skype crashed
i tried to uninstall/re-install it through the software center
but then that crashed....
I was told that line 57 is malformed in source.list. The source list could not be read
I am told that there may be unmet dependencies....
I have no idea what this is about.
can  someone tell me precisely what to input at the console
step by step, paint by the numbers
otherwise its off to the repairman $$$$
or a complete re-install of the entire system

Comment: Could you copy/paste the exact error without paraphrasing it? Edit your question and add the information. Just tell me if you already added the information using comments.

Answer (score 0):

**/etc/apt/sources.list** is goobered, err, I mean, has an invalid entry.

If you open a terminal window then do 
`nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
go to the 57th line and put a leading # at the beginning of that lines, then save the edited file, the problem will go away.

You may, should you wish, edit your question and include the entire sources.list file or just line 57 and the line above and below it to show us where the error might be.